Blazor lazy loading does not work with direct link
I am trying to implement Blazor (.Net8) hosted web app with lazy loading.
This this my project structure
Program.cs
using BlazorApp.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(LazyAssemblyLoader));

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(BlazorApp.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.Run();

Routes.razor
@using BlazorApp.Client.Layout
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Services
@using System.Reflection

@inject LazyAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly"
        OnNavigateAsync="OnNavigateAsync"
        AdditionalAssemblies="_lazyLoadedAssemblies">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
    <Navigating>
        <p>Page loading...</p>
    </Navigating>
</Router>

@code
{
    private readonly List<Assembly> _lazyLoadedAssemblies = [];

    private async Task OnNavigateAsync(NavigationContext context)
    {
        var assemblies = context.Path switch
        {
            "dashboard" => await assemblyLoader.LoadAssembliesAsync(new[]
            {
                "Dashboard.wasm"
            }),
            _ => []
        };

        _lazyLoadedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies);
    }
}

Dashboard.razor
@page "/dashboard"

<PageTitle>Dashboard</PageTitle>

<h3>Dashboard</h3>

It works well if navigate on the links in the navigation menu.
But it does not work, if enter link https://localhost:44302/dashboard directly in the browser
It's possible to resolve, if to add in Program.cs reference to Dashboard project
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
  .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
  .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(BlazorApp.Client._Imports).Assembly)
  .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Dashboard._Imports).Assembly);

But in this case the Dashboard page loads 2 times, if to enter it directly in the browser.

What Interactivity, and where?  Server/wasm/Auto and Global/Per Page/Component?

Also are you just seeing pre-rendering?  See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Global interactivity, wasm

"But in this case the Dashboard page loads 2 times, if to enter it directly in the browser."  It's called Pre-Render.  You are reloading the SPA.  See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerender?view=aspnetcore-8.0.  Do you want to disable pre-rendering?

I don't want to disable pre-rendering because that would prevent the page content from being visible to search engines. But double loading is not the main problem.
I want to use lazy loading to reduce the initial load size. And some pages are not available for many users at all, for example admin area. So I do not want to load them for all.
How properly to resolve the issue with direct link access?
